# Angular Services: Should I replicate service properties in components?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, service

When using it in the view, is there any drawback to not assigning a property living in a service (e.g. an array) to a component's own property, and instead accessing `service.property` directly?

```
export class Service {
  things: string[];
}
```

In some places I've seen it done like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class Component implements OnInit {
  things: string[];

  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.things = this.service.things;
  }
}
// HTML:
<div *ngFor="let thing of things"></div>
```

But I find that this works, too:

```
@Component({...})
export class Component {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}
// HTML:
<div *ngFor="let thing of service.things"></div>
```

Is there any difference? Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

There is a little difference, but you can use any of the two freely. the second way is working because when you use a modifier (e.g private) on one of the constructor parameters, that parameter becomes automatically a member of the class, so this:

```js
@Component({...})
export class Component {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}
// HTML:
<div *ngFor="let thing of service.things"></div>
```

is equal to this:

```js
@Component({...})
service: Service
export class Component {
  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.service = service;
  }
}
// HTML:
<div *ngFor="let thing of service.things"></div>
```

see more here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties

Comment: Yes! I know about the constructor parameters modifiers (: it was more about using the component's own property in the view (bound to that of the service) or simply/directly use the service in the view.